# How to boot from an external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have an old Compaq computer (5 years old), which came with Windows Vista. I made the recovery disks for the Operating System. A few days ago I took the hard drive out of the computer to use it as a portable hard drive, but now I want to install Windows on the previous Vista partition (50 GB).

I put my recovery disk in, booted from it, and installed factory OS to my HDD which works fine. I set the boot sequence to USB Hard drive and then CD/DVD Drive. My computer does not boot from the USB drive and the computer just comes up with a blank screen with a cursor blinking on it.

What do you guys think the problem is and how can I solve it?

Comment: Other than Win8 Exterprise's "Windows To Go" feature, Windows normally doesn't support booting from USB.

Answer (score 1):

is the bios recognizing the USB hard drive? Did you install the OS to the ext HD? Or just move the files.  The OS has to be directly installed to that hard drive. This one may help as well

[Booting from a USB drive that was originally a boot drive](https://superuser.com/questions/38683/booting-from-a-usb-drive-that-was-originally-a-boot-drive?rq=1)

Comment: I installed it on External hard drive. After installation it says 'Windows will restart automatically and continue installation' but when it restarts, a blank screen appears with a blinking cursor.